# How to return a pointer of array strings

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

```
  class test
{
private:
    string *firstname;
public:
    void setfname(const string fname[])
    {
        delete[] firstname;
        firstname = new string[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            firstname[i] = fname[i];
        }
    }
    string* getfname(const string fname[]) const
    {
        return firstname;
    }
};
```

ok now I know the return function is wrong because it's giving me direct access, how do i set up the function so it doesn't allow it.

This is how I am going to test it:

```
int main()
{
    test t;
    string narray[3] = { "Name1", "Name2", "Name3" };
    t.setfname(narray);

    cout << "\nAfter t.setfname(narray);"
        << "\nf.getfname(narray) follows: ";
    cout << t.getfname(narray);
}
```

I know getfname is wrong, how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `vector<string>` ?

Comment: By returning a pointer to const string, but I don't know why you think cout << t.getfname(narray);` would actually print out any strings. The only thing it will print is an adderess. Aside from that you alsow have to initialize your `firstnames` pointer to `nullptr` otherwise you'll get an segmentation fault for trying to delete a nonexisting array.

Comment: Why are you passing `const string fname[]` in `getfname()` ?

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, just return a copy of the string instead of a pointer:

```
string getfname(const string fname[]) const
{
    return *firstname;
}
```

Even better, store a string instead of a pointer to it:

```
class test
{
private:
    string firstname;
    ...
```

Comment: Its for a assignment and the teacher did that too make it hard.

Comment: So what part of the code are you allowed to change? Its hard to come up with solutions without knowing what restrictions are in place ;)

Comment: @JanRüegg: Are you aware, that the OP's class is handling an array of strings and not just one?

Comment: @MikeMB: Actually, I wasn't, you're completely right of course ;)